# How to start at a given arbitrary PageNumber

Tags: front-end

I have a Script with several sub-notebooks.
I want to start the page of the body-text at 1 with content and foreword before that page.

How can I assign a page number to show up in the print-out?

I tried in the Chapter-Cell:

```
CounterAssignments->{{"Chapter", 0},{"Page", 7}}
```

or

```
CounterAssignments->{{"Chapter", 0},{"PageNumber", 7}}
```

I can read the page-number within the notebook with

```
CounterBox["Page"]
```

but it doesn't show up in the printout.

My page-header starts like this:

```
PageHeaders->{{"","",""},{"Mathematik 1",FormBox[DynamicBox[ToBoxes[FEPrivate`RunningText["Subsection",10,""," .,",{},True,0],StandardForm]],TextForm],Cell[TextData[{CounterBox["Page"]}],"PageNumber"]}},
PageFooters->{  {"ll","lm","lr"},
{Cell[BoxData[GraphicsBox[TagBox[RasterBox[CompressedData["
1:eJztXGdQVdmWtmbmx9T86ar3Y+rV1LyZefW6re5WWhFoRERAwACNiBgAtTGh
```

Thank you very much for any help or hint.

Comment: by default a header is not normally printed on the first page. Go to the options inspect and look for "FirstPageHeader" and set that for your notebook and see if that helps

Comment: Thank you for editing my question and make it more readable.  Independently of wether the first page is indicated or not, I want to start at a prescribed page number. It might for example also be the case that I have to print in several charges, so one part have to start at page say 143 or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],
  PrintingStartingPageNumber -> 43,
  PageHeaders -> {{"", "", ""}, {"Mathematik 1", 
     FormBox[DynamicBox[
       ToBoxes[FEPrivate`RunningText["Subsection", 10, "", " .,", {}, 
         True, 0], StandardForm]], TextForm], 
     Cell[TextData[{CounterBox["Page"]}], "PageNumber"]}},
  PageFooters -> {{"ll", "lm", "lr"}, {"ll", "lm", "lr"}},
  PrintingOptions -> {
    "PrintingMargins" -> {{90, 90}, {60, 90}},
    "PaperSize" -> {596, 794},
    "PageSize" -> {596, 794},
    "PageHeaderMargins" -> {60, 60},
    "PageFooterMargins" -> {30, 30},
    "FirstPageFace" -> Right,
    "FirstPageHeader" -> True,
    "FirstPageFooter" -> False}];
```

which gives this when printed:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the info, this helps a little bit :)